Writing content of MemoryCache to database and race conditions
I am implementing in C# .NET a simple message consumer that reads off a queue a bunch of key, value pair messages and I need to maintain a dictionary of key -> [values seen so far] (this is MemoryCache _memoryCache in the code below). Because periodically I want to write that to a DB, appending the values to the current one found in the DB.
How to go about that? In the following code I am maintaining a ConcurrentDictionary of keys and every 30 minutes I am looping over the keys to append to the DB but I am afraid of race conditions (the app has several instances, each has several cores).
public class MyMessageConsumer : BaseMessageConsumer
{
    private readonly MemoryCache _memoryCache; // key -> [values]
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool> _memoryCacheKeys;
    private DateTime _lastUpdate;

    // not expanding here on the constructors etc that set _lastUpdate etc.

    internal async Task<MessageConsumeResult> UpdateAsync(string cacheKey, string value)
    {
        
        await UpdateMemoryCache(cacheKey, keyword);

        if (DateTime.Now > _lastUpdate.AddMinutes(30))
        {
            _lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
            foreach (var (cacheKey, _) in _memoryCacheKeys)
            {
                if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out HashSet<string> values))
                {
                    WriteToSomeDB()
                    _memoryCache.Remove(RemoveKey(cacheKey));
                }
            
            }
        }
        return MessageConsumeResult.Completed();
    }

    private async Task UpdateMemoryCache(string cacheKey, string value)
    {
        if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out HashSet<string> previousValues))
        {
            if (!previousValues.Contains(value))
            {
                previousValues.Add(value);
                _memoryCache.Set(AddKey(cacheKey), previousValues, TimeSpan.FromHours(48));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _memoryCache.Set(AddKey(cacheKey), new HashSet<string> { value }, TimeSpan.FromHours(48));
        }
    }

    private string AddKey(string key)
    {
        _memoryCacheKeys.TryAdd(key, true);
        return key;
    }

    private string RemoveKey(string key)
    {
        _memoryCacheKeys.TryRemove(key, out _);
        return key;
    }
}

I am not too familiar with concurrency but I am assuming I should introduce a lock when updating the MemoryCache (new value, and removal after insertion to the DB). Ideally I would like to just dump the result of the MemoryCache when it is about to expire!  But MemoryCache does not seem to provide such a feature. Hence the workaround I came up with.
Thanks so much for your insights, and have a nice day!

Could you maybe use DistributedCache instead ? One of its implementations is backed by a DB. Otherwise, I'd say let the DB handle concurrency. You might even, depending on your DB structure add an index on the keys to ensure no duplicate values. Depending on volume of data this might not work for you though

Thanks for your answer @Irwene  ! I am writing to ScyllaDB and will most likely have to fetch the existing value, append the new ones and overwrite the result. Any precaution I should add to my code in doing so? I guess I could write each message to the DB but I wanted to buffer things a little bit....

I'm not familiar with that particular DB. Could you maybe open a transaction, read the existing content, update then save ? Most DB that support transactions will force another concurrent transaction wanting to access the same data to wait for the previous one to finish to allow it to process.
